# Load link into target frame on hover

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, onmouseover

I have a page with 2 iframes, 1 nav frame, 1 content frame. I want to load a link from the nav from into the content on mouse over. Essentially the same behavior as clicking a link with target="f" but without having to click.

This `onmouseover="window.location=event.target.href"` works to autoload a link in general but I want it to do it in the iframe I specify.

Code for link in the nav frame.

```
<a target="f" href="pfh.html" onmouseover="window.location=event.target.href">pfh</a>
```

on click it goes to target frame f but the onmouseover event it loads in the current frame.

Comment: Add your code (look up 'how to ask' !) . Also, is there a reason why you need to use iframes?

Comment: i prefer to use iframes as I am most familiar with them plus I am pasting in links that already have the target code.

Answer (score 0):

I had searched along time here before posting but I did some experimenting & got it to work with help from this page [Target a Window or Frame Using JavaScript or HTML](https://www.thoughtco.com/target-a-window-or-frame-using-javascript-or-html-4092194)

```
 onmouseover="top.frames['f'].location=event.target.href"
```